# Angularjs filter a scope within controller to create new scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope variable that looks as follows:

```
 $scope.people = [
      {'id':'1' ,'name':'John','category':'m'},
      {'id':'2', 'name':'Jack','category':'m'},
      {'id':'3','name':'Mark','category':'m'},
      {'id':'4','name':'Ernie','category':'m'},
      {'id':'5','name':'Jane','category':'w'},
      {'id':'6','name':'Jill','category':'w'},
      {'id':'7','name':'Betty','category':'w'},
      {'id':'8','name':'Mary','category':'w'}
      ];
```

This is a sample scope variable i created for the puspose of this problem. But i will be getting this data from a service. What i would like to achieve is, how do i filter this scope variable in to different variables from within the controller?

For example, i want to make 2 new scopes as follows from the given scope:

```
$scope.men = [
          {'id':'1' ,'name':'John','category':'m'},
          {'id':'2', 'name':'Jack','category':'m'},
          {'id':'3','name':'Mark','category':'m'},
          {'id':'4','name':'Ernie','category':'m'}
          ];

$scope.women = [
          {'id':'5','name':'Jane','category':'w'},
          {'id':'6','name':'Jill','category':'w'},
          {'id':'7','name':'Betty','category':'w'},
          {'id':'8','name':'Mary','category':'w'}
          ];
```

How do i achieve this? Any knowledge will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function isMan(person){
    return person.category == 'm';
}

function isWoman(person){
    return person.category == 'w';
}

$scope.men = $scope.people.filter(isMan);
$scope.women = $scope.people.filter(isWoman);
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/Va6zj/)</kbd>

For older browsers you would need to polyfill filter.

Alternatively you could user underscore's [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function.

Comment: hi...it worked great. can you tell me if there is a similar way to join 2 scope variables?

Comment: The scope properties are just javascript types so you can use concat to concatenate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some javascript lib like underscore.js

As an example

```
  _.groupBy($scope.people, function(v){ return v.category == 'm' });
```

Not sure about source code.